# HTML button goes invisible on session expiry

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page that has a button on click of which a chain of events are triggered, it works good and shows up while page load and every time while the session is alive, but when the session expires, or when I hit the link in a different browser and log in, the button goes invisible. 
 It comes back after page refresh, but I don't want the button to go invisible on session expiry.

I used 
    window.location.reload()
 in the script tag by appending
    +"#reload"
 to the location. It refreshes the browser once after page reload, but it didn't work.

I also removed all styling element from the button to check if it was a CSS issue, but that didn't help either.

Has anyone faced any similar issues or at least knows what it could be? If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: Without example this cannot be answered.

Comment: Hello Neils, do you mean code for the above when you say example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I could think of a million reasons causing this behaviour. To reduce it to the real one I would have to see the behaviour actually happening in a debug console. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose the button inside a "div" and align it, because if it is disappearing that means its order or style issue.

```
<div align="left"><input type=submit....></div>
```

Comment: Hello, it already a part of a div tag and aligned. I suspected it to be a style issue, but removing all the styling and then putting them inline is not helping either.